# DLL no longer loads if built in Visual Studio 6

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp

I'm working on a Visual Studio 2005 C++ .NET application. For networking, it uses a network protocol DLL built in Visual Studio 6. (The DLL developer swears by the older tool.)

At some point, the Visual Studio 6 project was updated to 2005 by another developer. The DLL was rebuilt, but it did not work. In any case, they decided to downgrade back to 6. I didn't realize this, so I loaded the 2005 `.vcproj` and built it. I'm not sure that was the trigger, but I suspect so.

Now, I cannot load the DLL on my machine if it was built in 6. Windows acts as if the `.dll` file doesn't exist. If I use the Visual Studio 2005 build product, it loads properly and runs but some functionality is broken. The solution *would* be to upgrade and debug from 2005, but the other developer wants to continue with VS 6. However, it does work on other computers. All are running XP Professional SP3.

If I copy the program directory from a working installation to mine, `.exe` and `.dll` and all, it ceases to work. What could cause this?

I used the freeware ProcessExplorer program and verified that no other similar DLL is loaded, nor is any DLL loaded on the working installation's machine before I expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of these type of problems is that you are mixing different runtime libraries: the VS6 dll uses msvcr60.dll while the VS2005 dll uses msvcr70.dll (that is, unless someone told VS2005 to compile against the VS6 framework but that's not likely). Typical problem example: the application allocates through msvcr70, passes that chunk of memory to the dll which deallocates using msvcr60, but that one uses a different heap. Bang.

The real solution here is to make everything (app and dlls) use the same runtime or in other words: upgrade to the recent VisualStudio version. *It did not work* is just a sign that the code is rather poorly written or uses outdated features; in both cases a healthy solution would be refactoring, instead of fiddling around with an almost ancient compiler. Ssuppose the other developer keeps insisting on using VS6, what will happen within 5/10/15 years? Does he have any real good reasons to stick with VS6?

Comment: As you were writing your answer, we agreed to upgrade :) . And for that matter, we'll probably upgrade to 2008 or 2010 pretty soon too. For what it's worth, we double-checked that the runtime library is the same between the working and nonworking systems.

Comment: msvcr60.dll - never exists.